# How use CASE syntac in Stored Procedure on Netezza

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, netezza

i just a newbie in netezza (Running version netezza Release 7.1.0.1-P1 [Build 37788]), i have created query to load data from another database, this is my query :

```
CASE INSTR(B.WIFI.WIFI_DETAIL.LOCATION, ';') WHEN 0 THEN B.WIFI.WIFI_DETAIL.LOCATION ELSE BTRIM(SUBSTR(B.WIFI.WIFI_DETAIL.LOCATION, 1, INSTR(B.WIFI.WIFI_DETAIL.LOCATION, ';')-1)) END AS POI_NAME
```

it's run perfect, but when i put in stored procedure , this is have modified using the solution from @ScottMcG :

```
create or replace procedure SP_CREATE_TMP_F_WIFIID_AP_UTILISASI()
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS INT4 AS
BEGIN_PROC

DECLARE

BEGIN
    /* CREATE TABLE TMP AP UTILISASI WITHOUT CLIENT */
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        create TABLE TMP_F_AP_UTILISASI as select AVG(ANN.THROUGPUT_V) as AVG_THROUGHPUT
            , SUM(ANN.BYTES_SENT) AS SUM_SENT
            , SUM(ANN.BYTES_RECIEVE) AS SUM_RECIEVE
            , (SUM(ANN.BYTES_RECIEVE)+SUM(ANN.BYTES_SENT)) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
            , COUNT(ANN.C_MAC_ADDRESS) AS ASSOCIATED_CLIENT_COUNT
            , COUNT(ANN.USER_NAME) AS AUTHENTICATED_CLIENT_COUNT
            , MAX(ANN.TOTAL_WAKTU) AS MAX_SESSION_DURATION
            , ANN.AP_NAME
            , ANN.ASSO_TIME_V
            , ANN.PAKET_NAME
            , ANN.SSID
            , CASE INSTR(AD.LOCATION, ' || quote_literal (';') || ') WHEN 0 THEN AD.LOCATION ELSE BTRIM(SUBSTR(AD.LOCATION, 1, INSTR(AD.LOCATION, ' || quote_literal (';') || ')-1)) END AS POI_NAME
        FROM
            A.USR3.V_ALL_NMS_DETAIL AS ANN
        JOIN A.USR3.V_NMS_AP_DETAIL AS AD
            ON ANN.AP_NAME = AD.AP_NAME
        GROUP BY ANN.AP_NAME
            , ANN.ASSO_TIME_V
            , ANN.PAKET_NAME
            , ANN.SSID
            , AD.LOCATION
    ';

END;

END_PROC;
```

when i call the procedure, it's still not work :

```
ERROR: Cross Database Access not supported for this type of command
```

i call from database A, and the procedure build in A

maybe you have idea for solved my problem,,,

or maybe any one have another query to equal for this query :

```
CASE INSTR(AD.LOCATION, ' || quote_literal (';') || ') WHEN 0 THEN AD.LOCATION ELSE BTRIM(SUBSTR(AD.LOCATION, 1, INSTR(AD.LOCATION, ' || quote_literal (';') || ')-1)) END AS POI_NAME
```

Thx

Comment: you have to escape quotes ' in your SQL-string. ';') should become '';'')

Comment: hi @FrankHeikens , it's still error...error ERROR:  Attribute ';' not found

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's not CASE itself that is a problem. When using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure (e.g. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) it is necessary to escape the quotation marks that are embedded in the text.  You can do this in two (at least) ways.

Here are two examples of a stored procedure using a CASE statement with string literals.  The first uses two single quotes '' to represent an escaped single quote. The second used the quote_literal function.

Escaped Quotation Mark Version

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SAMPLE()
RETURNS INTEGER
EXECUTE AS CALLER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TESTING_TABLE SET COL1 =  CASE INSTR(COL2,'';'') WHEN 0 THEN ''NOT SEMICOLON'' ELSE ''SEMICOLON'' END';

END;
END_PROC;
```

QUOTE_LITERAL Function Version

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SAMPLE()
RETURNS INTEGER
EXECUTE AS CALLER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TESTING_TABLE SET COL1 =  CASE INSTR(COL2,' || quote_literal (';') ||
    ') WHEN 0 THEN ' || quote_literal('NOT SEMICOLON') || ' ELSE ' || quote_literal('SEMICOLON') || ' END';

END;
END_PROC;
```

You can reference the documentation and examples [for running dynamic SQL in Netezza here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_executing_dynamic_queries.html)

Comment: hi @ScottMcG , i have tried your suggest solution, but error :

ERROR: Cross Database Access not supported for this type of command

it's can't be cross database ?

Comment: when i put tables in one database, it's still appear error : ERROR: Cross Database Access not supported for this type of command

maybe you have another solution for solved this problem

thx

Comment: What version of Netezza are you running? Could up update your question text with the full new version with the quote_literal? Also what database is the stored procedure created in and what database are you calling it from? Show us the full context of the creation and the execution of the SP when you get cross database access error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    create or replace procedure SP_CREATE_TMP_F_WIFIID_AP_UTILISASI()
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS INT4 AS
BEGIN_PROC

DECLARE

BEGIN
    /* CREATE TABLE TMP AP UTILISASI WITHOUT CLIENT */
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        create TABLE TMP_F_AP_UTILISASI as select AVG(ANN.THROUGPUT_V) as AVG_THROUGHPUT
            , SUM(ANN.BYTES_SENT) AS SUM_SENT
            , SUM(ANN.BYTES_RECIEVE) AS SUM_RECIEVE
            , (SUM(ANN.BYTES_RECIEVE)+SUM(ANN.BYTES_SENT)) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
            , COUNT(ANN.C_MAC_ADDRESS) AS ASSOCIATED_CLIENT_COUNT
            , COUNT(ANN.USER_NAME) AS AUTHENTICATED_CLIENT_COUNT
            , MAX(ANN.TOTAL_WAKTU) AS MAX_SESSION_DURATION
            , ANN.AP_NAME
            , ANN.ASSO_TIME_V
            , ANN.PAKET_NAME
            , ANN.SSID
            , CASE INSTR(AD.LOCATION, ";") WHEN 0 THEN AD.LOCATION ELSE BTRIM(SUBSTR(AD.LOCATION, 1, INSTR(AD.LOCATION, ";")-1)) END AS POI_NAME
        FROM
            A.USR3.V_ALL_NMS_DETAIL AS ANN
        JOIN A.USR3.V_NMS_AP_DETAIL AS AD
            ON ANN.AP_NAME = AD.AP_NAME
        GROUP BY ANN.AP_NAME
            , ANN.ASSO_TIME_V
            , ANN.PAKET_NAME
            , ANN.SSID
            , AD.LOCATION
    ';

END;

END_PROC;
```

Comment: thx for your help, but it's still error :(. error :
ERROR:  Attribute ';' not found